# Mongodb: Deploy a minimal mongodb cluster into docker swarm

Tags: mongodb, docker-swarm

I'm trying to deploy a minimal mongodb cluster into my development swarm environment like this:

[image]

Up to now:

```
version: "3.3"

networks:
  net:
    driver: overlay

services:

  data1:
    image: mongo:3.6
    container_name: data1
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet datars --smallfiles --port 27017
    expose:
      - 27017
    networks:
      - net

  cfg1:
    image: mongo:3.6
    container_name: cfg1
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet cfgrs --smallfiles --port 27017
    expose:
      - 27017
    networks:
      - net

  mongos1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    container_name: mongos1
    command: mongos --configdb cfgrs/cfg1:27017
    expose:
      - 27017
    networks:
      - net
```

Into my config server, I'm getting these message:

> 2019-09-06T09:22:15.693+0000 I SHARDING [shard registry reload] Periodic reload of shard registry failed  :: caused by :: 134 could not get updated shard list from config server due to Read concern majority reads are currently not possible.; will retry after 30s,

Any ideas?